# How to pass frames captured by a function from another library to the OpenCV function?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

My camera comes with its own SDK and a library for working with video streams. But instead, it removes the ability to work with open libraries (the camera is simply not recognized by their respective functions). But I need to take advantage of the OpenCV-python . Since frames are transferred to RAM anyway, is there a way to capture them directly from there and pass some function from the VideoCapture class (read(), grab() or something else)?
If it helps, the camera is the Thorlabs Scientific Camera CM505.

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of links? to spare others a 5 minute websearch: https://www.thorlabs.com/software_pages/ViewSoftwarePage.cfm?Code=ThorCam

Comment: The question is not about the availability of the SDK and the documentation for it (as you decided). I need help specifically with fetching frames from memory and redirecting them to OpenCV functions. In the SDK provided to the camera, this is not (and it would be strange if it were).

Comment: no I posted that link so anyone who wants to help you does not have to search for the SDK first. you ask volunteers. value their time by providing a link. not everyone is willing to crawl through the messy thorlabs website. what is wrong with using the image data form the SDK? I see no reason why you should stick with OpenCVs capture stuff if you already have a numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look into their SDK. They even provide a Python API. So I'm not sure what your problem is.

You get the image data as a numpy array embedded in a `Frame` object. Which you can directly stuff into OpenCV.

From the manual:

> **Frame**
>
> ```
> class thorlabs_tsi_sdk.tl_camera.Frame(image_buffer, frame_count,
> time_stamp_relative_ns_or_null)
> ```
>
> Holds the image data and frame count returned by polling the camera
> for an image.

> **Properties**
>
> ```
> image_buffer
> ```
>
> `np.array(dtype=np.ushort)`: Numpy array of pixel data. This array is
> temporary and may be invalidated after polling for another image,
> rearming the camera, or closing the camera.

If you insist on accessing the camera from OpenCV have a look at https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html

I did not find Thorlabs in any list so you'll probably have to integrate it yourself. But I don't see any reason to do that. Control the camera with the SDK and process the images with OpenCV